# How can i compare a dataset value with an integer

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=0;
        int submitid=0;
        int controlid;
        int counter = 0;
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection connection ;
        SqlCommand command ;
        string sql = null;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        connetionString = "Data Source=localhost;database=Starbulk;Integrated Security=True";
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_1";
         connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            try
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Submit ID] FROM Table_1", connection);
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(ds,"Table_1");
            int value = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows);



           do{
            if (submitid != value){

             MessageBox.Show(submitid.ToString());
            }

          }while (submitid > 0);


                 connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception )


{
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }


    }


    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

Hi I have a database with 10 columns but I went to compare only one with an integer Submitted "ex. if (submitid != dataset.submitted){ submitted =dataset.submitted}" but for some reason I cant get that my program recognise my dataset.I am trying to do that with a do while or for loop but I don't found what I am missing?Thanks in advance.I know there are some novice errors but those are fixable

Comment: What are you trying to do here `int value = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows);`  ?? you probably need a value from a column like `int value = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0]);` *(first row first column)*

Comment: i am trying to cast to in because i wnt it to compare it in the if statement below but with no luck i want somehow to compare the whole column with that integer(submitid)

Comment: It is not clear to me what yo are trying to accomplish. What row do you want to use for converting [Submit ID]? If you wish to retrieve a single row. then perhaps a WHERE condition and using GetScalar would me more efficient.

Comment: @rontornambe Correct [Submit ID] is the one but conversation isnt necessary if there is another way to compare my int with the dataset.the thing is that i want to compare the whole colum of Submit id with my in t in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to filter the dataset using a where clause. This is a simpler and more efficient way of achieving the results you seek (if I understand you correctly). I am assuming [Submit ID] is defined as an integer to the database, otherwise you will need include a CAST statement, ex. CAST ([Submit ID] AS int) - SQL-Server syntax

```
SELECT [Submit ID] FROM Table_1 WHERE [Submit ID] = 0
```

or to set value to any value use a parameter

```
SELECT [Submit ID] FROM Table_1 WHERE [Submit ID] = @value

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("value", submitid));
```

I would also recommend you have a look at  [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) to improve your code (see the "using" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use zero-based index.

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
```

or

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["columnName"]
```